# ​ Pytorch version of ApproxNDCGLoss

Tags: pytorch, tensorflow2.0, pytorch-lightning

How do you convert the TensorFlow [ApproxNDCGLoss](https://www.tensorflow.org/ranking/api_docs/python/tfr/keras/losses/ApproxNDCGLoss) to Pytorch?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like torch lightning has an implementation

https://lightning.ai/docs/torchmetrics/stable/retrieval/normalized_dcg.html